# Converting GMT to Server local time zone C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gmt, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert GMT time that I get from ebay API into a specific time zone , depending on where my application is hosted  so that I can convert and get correct dates (As they really are on ebay as well for transactions).

The way I tried to do it:

```
  DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(doc2.GetElementsByTagName("CreatedTime").Item(i).InnerText), DateTimeKind.Utc);
  order.OrderDate = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
```

But this is not working as I'm expecting it to ...

Any suggestions guys?

Edit: Sry I'm using ebay timestamp of transaction that I get, previously I said its Paypal but its actually ebay... Corrected it now..

Okay so I was expecting to re-create the graph that I have on my ebay accont like following:

[image]

And the graph that I get is nothing alike the one I have on eBay, by returning the same data from ebay and that graph...

This is what they told me on ebay developer site:

```
The eBay API returns time-stamps for events and transactions in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

Your application needs to handle the conversion between GMT and that time zone.

Please refer to the following knowledge base article:

https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=76

Regards
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve, based on this reply above...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?" Can you give an example of what you expected to happen and what actually happened instead?

Comment: Yeah one moment @EJoshuaS

Comment: @EJoshuaS I edited my question , can you look into it ? :)

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset instead of assuming what the local time offset is. Better yet, use NodaTime to specify the timezone itself, not just the offset.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you reply in a form of answer so that I can see how you think it should be done ?

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding this correctly: if there was a sale at 7:00 Central Time on 12/20/2016, you'd expect that the graph would show the sale being made on 12/20/2016 but it's actually showing up as being on 12/21 (since it would be 3:00 AM GMT at the time)? Or am I misreading this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes that is exactly the problem

Comment: Can you give an example of a particular value for doc2.GetElementsByTagName("CreatedTime").Item(i).InnerText and what convertedDate ends up being for that value?

Comment: @EJoshuaS yes sure , one moment

Comment: @EJoshuaS Ow theres a problem, the only date that I can get from ebay is just date itself, I don't have the exact time of the transactions...

Comment: Really? That's annoying on their part...

Comment: @EJoshuaS yeah :/ they only provide the date of the transaction on the panel, not the time itself :(

Comment: Is there a way of of having them include the timestamp so you can convert it to your preferred timezone?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I believe that the CreatedTime parameter that is returned with transaction is the time of the transaction in GMT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131083/discussion-between-user987-and-ejoshuas).